# How to do embroidery on tulle netting fabric?

Tags: embroidery, technique-selection

Has anybody ever tried embroidering floral designs by hand on tulle or other netting fabrics (see picture) and has some ideas and suggestions?
Do we need any special needle or tools for embroidering on netting fabric?

[image: Net fabric]

Comment: Hi Anushree, can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean "net fabric?" Are you embroidering by hand or machine? What's the intended result?

Comment: Hi @Joachim I have tried embroidery on cotton cloths but not on any net fabric.

Comment: @AllisonC I have attached an image of net fabric. I don't know any other word for this.
The intended result should be design patterns with threads like the embroidery we do on normal cloths.

Comment: Again, are you embroidering by hand or machine? What kind of designs? What kind of result? Please be specific or no one can give you an effective answer. :)

Comment: @AllisonC I want to embroider by hand , not machine. Floral designs. I am just asking for suggestions if anybody has tried on such kind of a fabric.

Comment: What is the result you're looking for? Just outlines like vintage embroidery or redwork? Fully filled embroidery? What do you want to use it for, display or garments? These are all details that will help with an answer that will help you and others.

Answer (score 1):

You can use all embrodery technics as long as you realize that the back will be visible. Not just the back, the threads will be visible all along, but so do the knots and mistakes.

It is likely best to keep your fabric in a hoop or stretched over a frame, so you will not draw it in while working.

There are special stitches which are the same front and back. You can find them online or in older books.
One stitch I remember is like weaving, filling a few holes at a time.

But you are not restricted to those stitches, you can use most stitches, as long as the 'back' does not spoil the front.

I just ran a google search on -embroidery on tulle- and got so many results that I tried to specify and added -stitches- but the results are still way to many to pick one.
If you like videos, youtube has several.
This is a random one that I liked when I saw it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzq5d3pP6IQ

And this is a text and pictures page, which does explain how to work on tule, again a random choice, I have no links with the site or people behind it:
https://crewelghoul.com/blog/how-to-hand-embroider-on-tulle/